# Given a list of strings how can I separate them into strings?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have the following list of strings:

```
a = ['a','the quick fox', 'b', 'c', 'hi there']
```

How can I transform it into:

```
'a','the quick fox', 'b', 'c', 'hi there'
```

I tried to:

```
 "','".join(a)
```

However, its returning me this:

```
"hey','the quick fox','b','c','hi there"
```

Instead of:

```
'hey','the quick fox','b','c','hi there'
```

Comment: The output you want isn't a valid representation of a Python object. Do you want a string? A tuple?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want a single string with the items serrated by commas?

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes like: `'CCANTON AKRON', 'CAANTON AKRON', 'CANNTON AKRON', 'CANTTON'`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the quotes as part of the `join`, you can instead get the `repr` [representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr/2626364#2626364) of each string, which will include the quotes, then join those:

```
print(', '.join(map(repr, a)))
# 'a', 'the quick fox', 'b', 'c', 'hi there'
```

Comment: now I end up with something like this: `"'a', 'the quick fox', 'b', 'c', ""hi there'`

Comment: The `join` will produce the string `"'a', 'the quick fox', 'b', 'c', 'hi there'"`, which when printed looks like `'a', 'the quick fox', 'b', 'c', 'hi there'`, just like the string `"dog"` looks like `dog` when printed.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: Do not confuse the output you see in the Python console with the actual contents of a variable. This answer is giving you the correct value, but just doing this `', '.join(map(repr, a))` at the Python prompt will show you the repr of the value, which wraps strings in single or double quotes, to show that they are strings. Try assigning to a variable like this `list_as_str = ', '.join(map(repr, a))`, and then print out `list_as_str` using `print(list_as_str)`. If at the Python prompt you just do `list_as_str` to see its contents, you will get the repr again.